# django_tastypie can't recognize url

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am starting a new project with **Django** and **neo4j**, and the most promising library for developing REST services is **TastyPie** (**Django Rest Framework** is to tied to ORM, and **neo4j** is not a relational database).

I am following [this tutorial](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non_orm_data_sources.html) in order to make **TastyPîe** to work with not relational databases, and I already override the get methods, but I get this error when trying to access the endpoint:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/items_manager/items/
Using the URLconf defined in AttractoraGraph.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
api/ general/
api/ items_manager/ items/ ^(?P<resource_name>item)/$ [name='api_dispatch_list']
api/ items_manager/ items/ ^(?P<resource_name>item)/schema/$ [name='api_get_schema']
api/ items_manager/ items/ ^(?P<resource_name>item)/set/(?P<pk_list>.*?)/$ [name='api_get_multiple']
api/ items_manager/ items/ ^(?P<resource_name>item)/(?P<pk>.*?)/$ [name='api_dispatch_detail']
The current path, api/items_manager/items/, didn't match any of these.
```

This is my general **urls.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import path, include

api_url_patterns = [
    path('general/', include('GeneralApp.urls')),
    path('items_manager/', include('ItemsManagerApp.urls')),
]

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(api_url_patterns)),
```

This is my application's **urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from ItemsManagerApp import resources

urlpatterns = [
    path('items/', include(resources.ItemResource().urls)),
]
```

this is my **resources.py**:

```
from tastypie import fields, utils
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from tastypie.resources import Resource
from ItemsManagerApp import models

class ItemResource(Resource):
    uid = fields.CharField(attribute='uid')
    name = fields.CharField(attribute='name')
    description = fields.CharField(attribute='description')
    created = fields.DateTimeField(default=utils.now, attribute='created')

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        return list(Item.nodes.all())

    def obj_get_list(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        return self.get_object_list(bundle.request)

    def obj_get(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        item = Item.nodes.filter(uid=kwargs['pk'])

        return item
```

I can see that the endpoint url `api/items_manager/items/` is in the list, but with something else that is not referenced in the documentation.

I'll appreciate any idea of how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, you can try to access this endpoint `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/items_manager/items/item/`.

Maybe [this tutorial](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html#resource-name) can help you.